# I would like to start the cluster resources 5 at a time only

Tags: powershell

We had a 4 Hyper-V clusters with 2012 R2 and VM's are running on it.

I would like to start the cluster resources 5 at a time only and i had tried following command as per MS but it is not working as expected.

instead of 5 Vm it is starting all VM's any help appreciated

```
Get-Cluster -name cluster1 | Get-ClusterResource | where { $_.Name -and $_.state -eq "offline"} –ob 5 | Start-ClusterResource
```

Comment: Hi All-  Than you and the script is working as expected.

Comment: I need to run the command in a loop with 2 minutes break time can someone please help on it.

Comment: Wrapping my answer in a simple [do while loop](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_loops_do_while.htm) and using `Start-Sleep` should do that.

Comment: Thank you very much and i had created the script and it is working as per my requirements

Answer (score 0):

I've not got a HyperV Cluster to test this on, but `Select-Object -First 5` will select only 5 of the returned Cluster Resources:

```
Get-ClusterResource -Cluster cluster1 | where { $_.State -eq "Offline"} | Select-Object -First 5 | Start-ClusterResource
```

Comment: He wants to restart all resources, but in batches of 5 at a time.